# Understanding done function in PassportJS

Tags: node.js, passport.js, passport-local

I am trying to implement a normal login and signup module and I am facing difficulty in understanding the done function.[here](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-local/blob/master/lib/strategy.js#L80) is the line I feel is responsible for the done function. Now what I wanted to do was return the corresponding messages like if there was some server error.

```
app.post('/user/auth/login', passport.authenticate('local-login'), function(req, res) {
    console.log("Login Request Successful");
    if(req.user){
        res.status(200).send(JSON.stringify({
            'msg' : "Successfully logged in"
        }));
    }
    else{
        res.status(400)
    }
    //console.log(req.user);
});
```

This is for the case when after logging in Passport attaches a user object to the request module. 
But how do I differentiate between a server error and authentication failed error

Here is my authenticate middleware.

```
passport.use('local-login', new LocalStrategy({
    passReqToCallback: true
}, function(req, username, password, done) {

    Users.findOne({
        'emailId': username
    }, function(err, user) {
        if (err)
            return done(err);
        if (!user)
            return done(null, false);
        else if (passwordHash.verify(password, user.password)) {
            console.log("User is verified");
            req.session.save();
            return done(null, user);

        } else
            return done(null, false);
    });
}));
```

Basically, I need to access the messages in done() function. How do I do that?

How does function, like if I type the wrong password, the message I get in my browser in Unauthorized. It means somewhere it is setting the response.data field to Unauthorized. Instead of that I want to know when there is an error and want to send my custom message.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know what do you mean by

> access the messages in done() function

, however You can very well do with supplying addition object with message in **done** callback

```
if (!user) {
    return done(null, false, {
                message: 'Unknown user or invalid password'
    });
}
if (!user.authenticate(password)) {
    return done(null, false, {
                message: 'Unknown user or invalid password'
    });
}
```

Comment: Somehow in my response.data in angular the message field doesn't show up. Any possible reason?

Comment: Got it... __useful for displaying a flash message prompting the user to try again__ . But I don't want it as a flash message I want to show it as toaster notification.

Comment: Its completely your call how you want to display message :)

Answer (score 1):

Another method. 
I don't know how I missed it. There is an option of custom callbacks in the docs. Here is the implementation of the same.

```
 app.post('/user/auth/login', function(req, res) {
        passport.authenticate('local-login', function(err, user, info) {
        if (err) {
             res.status(500).send(JSON.stringify({
                'msg': "Internal Server Error"
            }));
        }
        if (!user) {
           res.status(401).send(JSON.stringify({
                'msg': "Username or Password is incorrect"
            }));
        }
        if (user) {
            res.status(200).send(JSON.stringify({
                'msg': "Successfully logged in"
            }));
        }
    })(req, res, next);
    });
```

The only issue with this solution is that you will have to manually login and create session and all that.

> - An optional `callback` can be supplied to allow the application to overrride the default manner in which authentication attempts are
>     handled.  The  callback has the following signature, where `user`
>     will be set to the authenticated user on a successful
>     authentication attempt, or `false` otherwise.  An optional `info`
>     argument will be passed, containing additional details provided by
>     the strategy's verify callback.

```
app.get('/protected', function(req, res, next) {
passport.authenticate ('local',function(err, user, info) {
if (err) { return next(err) } 
if (!user) { return res.redirect('/signin') }
res. redirect('/account');  
})(req, res, next);
});
```

> Note that if a callback is supplied, it becomes the application's  responsibility to log-in the user, establish a session, and otherwise
>   perform   the desired operations.

Comment: Interesting, however I tried to answer that way you wanted it to be at first attempt :)